# Add plain Android library to a Flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-plugin

This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55005818/5735864). But it has no answer and I will give some details here.

I have created a module with **File->New Module->Android Library** inside my Flutter plugin's android project. And now I have a structure like below:

```
|-my_plugin
  |-android
    |-settings.gradle
    |-build.gradle
    |-mylibrary
      |-build.gradle
```

**/android/settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'my_plugin'
include ':mylibrary'
```

**/android/build.gradle**:

```
...
dependencies {
  implementation project(':mylibrary')
}
```

When I build example plugin project (which is automatically created by Flutter CLI) with **flutter build apk** or **flutter run**, I get this error:

```
Project with path ':mylibrary' could not be found in project ':my_plugin'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: uuhg, the flutter website is also wrong stating we have to import the project. the flutter plugin development on android studio is broken for sure

Comment: @negative_zero, are you able to use library module in flutter plugin? any update?

Comment: @SatyaAttili No, at least I couldn't back then and couldn't find anything useful. I had to copy all the files from the library. I will check it later and update the question if it's fixed or there is something useful.

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for a solution. You can try this.

Instead of putting the below code in the plugin setting.gradle, place it in example/android/settings.gradle

```
include ':mylibrary'
```